# 2 subnets off of 1 PC with 2 NICs

Tags: configuration, ip, subnet

I have a general setup I'd like to do with some IP cameras. This seems like it will work but I think I may be missing something. Our system consists of a video recorder PC connected to a switch which is connected to a number of IP cameras. I'd like to connect this system into an existing network but I want it on a different subnet. The main reason is that the cameras use a lot of bandwidth that I don't want slowing down the existing network.

My idea was to install 2 NICs on the video recorder pc. 1 NIC connects to the existing network on 192.169.1.x for example, and the other NIC connect to the switch with the cameras. This NIC would be 192.168.100.x.

Then we could remote to the video recorder PC with a GoToMyPC type thing for administration via the existing network.

I've included a diagram of how I see this working but I'm a little fuzzy on the setup of the NICs (if this can work at all).

My problem may be trying to deal with 2 subnets without a router but It really doesn't seem like it's necessary in this situation.

BTW, gliffy is cool.
[image]
<sub>(source: [adapttosolve.com](http://adapttosolve.com/images/Typical_Camera_Setup.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One fairly common configuration error in this kind of setup is assigning gateway IPs on both NICs.  In the diagram above, the netmasks for both NICs would be 255.255.255.0 and the gateway IP should be assigned on eth0 (probably 192.168.1.1) and left **empty** on eth1.  Otherwise should be fine.

Comment: So it should be--
eth0::
ip: 192.168.1.100 (outside existing network DHCP range)
snmask: 255.255.255.0; gateway: (whatever gateway of existing network is)
eth1::
ip: 192.168.100.1; snmask: 255.255.255.0; gateway: [blank]

?

Comment: That's correct, assuming your existing eth0 subnet is 192.168.1.0/24.

Comment: That's the only subnet I know so I'm sure it is :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely possible.  Just set each nic with the appropriate network configuration.

Depending on your OS, you can specify internet traffic to be routed through eht0.

Comment: +1 Should work like a charm.

Comment: To route the traffic through the PC , as a gateway, just enable connection sharing on the NICs